# Display children inside component

Tags: vue.js, children

My question is simple: How can I render the children of my component?

I have a template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <menubar color="#263238">
      <button>click</button>
    </menubar>
  </div>
</template>
```

and `menubar` is the component I created. How can I now render the button-tag inside the `menubar` component?

Comment: You can add button in your child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use slots for this. Please, check the link in the Vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html.

[image]

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!